# Qt Model-View update view?

Tags: qt, view

I have a model which is updated dynamically not related to the view. Which method should be called on the view to show the current models data?

Example:

```
StationListModel *model = new StationListModel(dynamic_list);
QListView *view = new QListView;
view->setModel(model);  //view set with empty model 
view->show();
```

In some point in time the `dynamic_list` is populated with new entries via a socket connection (nothing to do with View). How to populate the view with new data?

Comment: There is a `QAbstractItemView::update(const QModelIndex & index)`. `QAbstractItemView` is the base class of `QListView`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Model must emit signals to notify views when its data changed. Choose appropriate signals depending on how exactly data is changed:

- `dataChanged` signal forces view to update specific cells, but not to create or remove cells.
- `layoutAboutToBeChanged` and `layoutChanged` signals forces view to update everything.
- signals about adding or removing rows and columns forces view to update accordingly.

Comment: What are the slots on the view that can catch them?

Comment: It's internal view implementation. Views connect to the model's signals automatically. You don't need to think about it.

Comment: So after setting `view->setModel(model);` the view should update itself on every model change (assuming `dataChanged` or `layoutChanged` emmited) ?

Comment: Yes, assuming that signals are emitted in correct order and with correct parameters.

Comment: @alan actually you shouldn't emit `layoutAboutToBeChanged` and friends directly but instead use the `beginInsert` and `endInsert` and family which will in turn emit the necessary signals

Comment: @alan: *So after setting view->setModel(model); the view should update itself on every model change* That's the **whole point** of the model-view architecture. It'd be next to useless otherwise.

Comment: any subclass that overrides "`QListView::timerEvent(...)`" should call it manually to ensure `paintEvent` gets called (that did fix my case)